# cms and multilanguage

Tags: database-design, content-management-system

I'm trying to develop a mini cms, is it more flexible to have a "translated copy" of an article by language or a multilanguage article?

I'm working with Django but it's more a pb of logical and model design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to have a table with all available languages. The article table just store a primary key and article related things. But no title and no content. Then you have a translated article table. This table has a one to one relation to the language table and a many to one relation to the article table.